# RPI 3B+ refuses ssh and VNC connection

Tags: ssh, pi-3b+, vnc

I have a Rpi 3B+ that I set up yesterday to work with Kodi as a media center through a WiFi connection. The only problem is that yesterday I could connect via VNC and ssh to the Rpi, and today I can't. I'm getting a "connection refused" message either way.

Since yesterday, when it worked, I have changed absolutely nothing, and before anybody asks I'm aware that ssh and VNC come disabled by default. I activated them when I installed a fresh Raspbian. Today they are still (!) active, in theory. Not in practice, of course.

I have tried rebooting and disabling and enabling ssh and VNC again, but nothing happens. I always get "Connection refused".

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you reboot your Pi between the time you were last logged on and now? You can always connect the Pi to a screen and plug in a keyboard if you have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, and it had nothing to do with the Rpi (I'm posting it here just in case somebody else has the same problem).

It was a matter of conflicting (i.e., equal) IP addresses, that were assigned through DHCP. I set the new conflicting IP as static (with a different number) and solved the problem.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.